# Receiving ETIMEOUT 104.20.58.10:443 error when request to `horizon.stellar.org`

Tags: horizon

`ETIMEOUT 104.20.58.10:443` I sometime receive this error when request to `horizon.stellar.org`. What is this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ETIMEOUT` is "error - timeout". There are many possibilities, for example, your network is unstable and the traffic cannot be successfully returned. Please supply more information on your situation and details & error message.

`104.20.58.10:443` is the actual IP address where this Horizon lies at. View this with `CTRL + i` with Firefox/Chrome.

[image]

Comment: I am pooling to `horizon.stellar.org` to check health because of using `horzion.stellar.org` for submitting transaction.  sometimes I receive a few the error `connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.59.10:443`in pooling server . in addition, pooling server and the submitting transaction server are different. In this situation, am i
no problem to submitting transciton through `horizon.stellar.org`?

Comment: After some search, it is kind of `network timeout` as you said. Then, do you know when ETIMEDOUT occurred in a network situation? i,g , expired cookie

Comment: `ETIMEDOUT` have numerous causes, and can be from client side or server side. If it is at server side, it could be from Stellar-Core or Horizon; if at client side, it could be due to the modules, sdk or network binder itself. So...you better print out more extra info on the error message, so as to narrow down the scope to find the origin of error.

Comment: I only have `connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.59.10:443` error message. So, I will gather more info. Before trying this, Could you give some idea how to get more info? using `tcpdump`?

Comment: i assume that you are using CLI tools. Could you store the reponse message and output it in full? Not sure how you make a request to Horizon... (for me, i always use the js-stellar-sdk to send request, so i just log down the entire response json object)